# Web app with svgs

Tags: google-chrome, svg, google-chrome-app

I'm making a Chrome App and need to package images with the app, so they will not be served by an external server. I'm attempting to load local svg files, but in Chrome (Version 40.0.2214.111 m) in all my efforts to display the svgs keep getting the error `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/svg`

Ideally I am trying to find a way to load local svgs in `<img>` tags. Is there a way to do this locally? I understand that svgs that are served contain proper headers telling Chrome how to display svgs in img tags, but I cannot get this to work with locally stored svgs.

Please don't suggest using pngs unless you know that is the only solution. I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This problem I had with the fonts, the way in which I decided was to use:

```
src: url(data:application/x-font-woff; base64,/*..file data...*/)
```

In your case, try a method of using SVG files in local mode